# How do I keep WordPress from formatting out leading spaces?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, formatting

I'm trying to post some code snippets on my WordPress blog, but when I copy and paste, it strips out all the leading spaces from each line of code.  It doesn't seem to have a problem with leading spaces being there in general, since I can add them back in manually, but it doesn't like them being pasted in for whatever reason.

Is there some plugin I can use, or some simple code modification I can make, to make it accept the code I paste in without trying to format it for me?

Comment: It strips them out when you paste in Code mode? Or Editor mode?

Sorry, obvious question, but had to ask.

Comment: So I guess this is programming related because you are trying to post code snippets?

Comment: That and because the solution may well involve changing the code in one way or another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the code editor (NOT Visual) and wrap your code in

```
<pre></pre>
```

tags. Then format appropriately in your theme's CSS.

Here's [Wordpress' explanation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts)

Comment: This does not explain why only leading spaces are lost but no other formatting. I acually save OpenOffice Writer into HTML and get the same stripping locally, without any WordPress or Blogger.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the FCKEditor (now called CKEditor) plugin, http://www.deanlee.cn/wordpress/fckeditor-for-wordpress-plugin/. I find it works a lot better than the built-in TinyMCE default editor. The only time I haven't used it is when I have sites that use the qTranslate plugin as it does not currently support CKEditor.